# Call frame control from viewmodel on Windows universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, frame

my code of MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:x1="using:System"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Frame HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Name="frameMainPage"></Frame>
```

My code from LoginViewModel.cs

```
...
if (m_login.Username == "username" && m_login.Password == "password")
                        {
                            Singleton.User = m_login;
                            App.log.Info("Success! Login done!");
                            //load in frame the dashboard page after login.
                        }
...
```

How to get my frame and load in Dashboard.xaml page ?
It's possible do this from viewmodel ?

My target is load a pages in the MainPage.xaml frame.
Thanks

Comment: *How to get my frame and load in Dashboard.xaml page ?*  Which frame do you want to load? `MainPage` ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I want call frameMainPage from viewmodel and load new page inside it frame.

Answer (score 0):

> I want call frameMainPage from viewmodel and load new page inside it frame.

For this scenario, you could use Frame [`SourcePageType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.sourcepagetype#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls) property to realize. If you want to the Frame loads a new page, you could modify `SourcePageType`'s binding item like the follow.

```
internal class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Type _nextPage;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Type NextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return _nextPage;
        }
        set
        {
            _nextPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
         _nextPage = typeof(HomePage);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Frame SourcePageType="{Binding NextPage,Mode=TwoWay}">
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```